# Sending Attachment in Soap using Jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, attachment

I am starting with Soap and I have to send a soap response with few details along with a pdf file attachment.

**AllDetails.java**

```
public class AllDetails implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name,address;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**GetDetails.java**

```
    public interface GetDetails {

    public AllDetails getDetails(String name, String address);
}
```

**GetDetailsImp**

```
public class GetDetailsImp implements GetDetails {

    @Override
    public AllDetails getDetails(String name, String address) {
        AllDetails obj = new AllDetails();
        obj.setName("siddhesh");
        obj.setAddress("badlapur");
        
        
        try {
            MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
            
            DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource("D:\\test\\random.pdf");
            
            AttachmentPart attachmentPart = message.createAttachmentPart(dataSource , "content-type");
            message.addAttachmentPart(attachmentPart);
            message.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I have created sample we service but along with Details object I also want to send attachment which is a pdf file

**XML Response**

[image]